# why not square of quadratic sigma?

Tags: linear-algebra

sorry i'm so bad at math. I'm reading a math related tutorial. If

$\sigma i = \sigma j = \sigma$

Why

[image]

give result as

$\sqrt(\sigma^2)$

and not

$\sigma^2$ ?

The computation formula (just ignore the means and the `P` parts) in this case :

[image]

and she counted like this :

[image]

And I don't understand what she means by this (again, ignore other things such as the east and west part, the most important part is $\sigma i = \sigma j$):

Comment: @DavidK, the red box in the third picture. But, it's all my mistake, i misunderstood the context.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot follow your context. But if $\sigma_i=\sigma _ j =\sigma $, then $$\sqrt {\sigma_i^2\sigma_j^2}=\sqrt {\sigma^4}=\sigma^2. $$

Comment: Then she was wrong right?

Comment: If $\sigma^2=1.039067$, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I've upvoted it. Actually it was on my side that misunderstand things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, the misunderstanding is actually on my side.

Actually it's not about

$$\sigma_i = \sigma_j = \sigma$$

but, rather,

$$\sigma_i^2  = \sigma_j^2 = x$$

So

$$\sqrt{\sigma_i^2\sigma_j^2} = x$$

So she was **CORRECT**.

I was confused about standard *deviation* ($\sigma$) and *variance* ($\sigma^2$).